# Find the value of $n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Write the value of $n$ if the sum of n terms of the series $1+3+5+7...n =n^2$.

I'm not getting the right value if I proceed with the general formula for finding sum of n terms of a arithmetic series. The general summation formula for arithmetic series is $\frac{n(2a+(n-1)d)}{2}$, where $a$ is the first term, $d$ is the common difference and $n$ is the number of terms.

Comment: If you use the given formula, you have (because of $a=1$ and $d=2$) : $\frac{n(2+2(n-1))}{2}=\frac{n\cdot 2n}{2}=n^2$. But if we have $n$ summands, the last summand is not $n$ , but $2n-1$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since we have $$1+3+5+7+\cdots (2n-1)=n^2$$ and we want to have $$1+3+5+7+\cdots +n=n^2$$ we must have $2n-1=n$ , which implies $n=1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the sum of an arithmetic progression with $n$ terms having a starting term $a$ and common difference $d$ is: $$S_n = \frac{n}2 \left[2a + (n-1)d\right]$$ Now, if $a=1, d=2$, what do you get?

$$S_n = \frac{n}{2}\left[2+(n-1)2\right] = \frac{n}{2}\left[2n \right] = n^2$$

Comment: n on both side gets cancelled

Comment: Can you please explain the problem in a better way

Comment: n gets cancelled

Comment: If we take n=10 then the equation is satisfied However how to get it

Comment: You have to find the expression. Note that it is valid for all $n$. The sum of the first **$n$ odd numbers is always $n^2$**.

Comment: $n/2(2×a+(n-1)×d) =n^2$. From here we get

Comment: Note that the sum of the first n odd numbers is always $n^2$. But, there is one catch. Note that the expression for the nth odd number is $(2n-1$), as you can verify for yourself. But, the last term in your expression is given as $n$. Equating the two, we have:$$2n-1=n \implies n=1$$

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If we add $2+4+...+(n-1) = 2(1+2+3+...+\frac{n-1}{2})$ to both sides of the equation, we get 
$$1+2+3+...+n = n^2+2\bigg(1+2+3+...+\frac{n-1}{2}\bigg)$$
which can be written as:
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = n^2+2\bigg[\frac{\big(\frac{n-1}{2}\big)\big(\frac{n+1}{2}\big)}{2} \bigg]$$
that is
$$\frac{n^2+n}{2} = n^2+\frac{n^2-1}{4} \implies n^2+n = \frac{5n^2-1}{2} \implies 3n^2-2n-1 = 0 \implies n = 1$$
because $n$ is not a negative number.